# SQL Server 2008 name list based on multiple character alphas

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have been working on this query almost two days. There is a table for staff as following. Each location has multiple staff who get list of customer they need to take care of it based on the listed alphas. however alphas are not standard single or double characters instead they have put single thru three letters as you can see on the table. I am trying to get customer list and their assign staff based on customers last name in those alpha range, I tried many queries and all they are failing in some level.

[image]

I used a couple of cte to get everything in order and tried following max

```
declare @maxChar varchar(3) = (select min(len(val)) from (
select  staffStartChar val from StaffAlphaList where staffLocId = 1 
union 
select  staffEndChar from StaffAlphaList where staffLocId = 1
)temp)

    select customerName
     , upper(LTRIM(RTRIM(
                LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(employee.f_name, ''))) + ' ' + 
                LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(employee.m_name, ''))) + ' ' + 
                LTRIM(ISNULL(employee.l_name, ''))
                )))
    from Customers  with (nolock)
    left outer join StaffAlphaList with (nolock)
        on StaffAlphaList.staffLocId= Customers.LocId
    left outer join employee with (nolock)
        on employee.empl_no = StaffAlphaList.staffId 
    where lower(left(customerLastName, @maxChar)) between StaffAlphaList.staffStartChar and StaffAlphaList.staffEndChar
```

Comment: Set [Bad Habits to kick - putting NOLOCK everywhere](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/) - it is *not recommended* to use this everywhere - quite the contrary!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
select c.*, sal.*
from customers c left join
     staffalphalist sal
     on sal.staffLocId = c.LocId and
        left(c.customerLastName, len(sal.startchar)) >= sa.startchar and
        left(c.customerLastName, len(sal.endchar)) <= sa.endChar;
```

Actually, I'm not sure exactly what output you want, but this lists the staff assigned to each customer.

Comment: Thank you so much, It is working perfectly now. I think I was overthinking this and focusing mostly alpha sets instead of whole.